# Cant resolve linking error

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I need to include the proxygen library in my project. Everything has been successfully installed. The only problem is that there is a linking error in the project that I am unable to resolve.

The OS I am working in is Ubuntu 14.04.

Here is the error log:

```
/home/cortana/clion-2016.1.3/bin/cmake/bin/cmake --build /home/cortana/.CLion2016.1/system/cmake/generated/string_from_url-a5f32588/a5f32588/Debug --target tutifruti -- -j 4
[ 33%] Linking CXX executable /home/cortana/ClionProjects/string_from_url/build/tutifruti
CMakeFiles/tutifruti.dir/src/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/cortana/ClionProjects/string_from_url/src/main.cpp:114: undefined reference to `proxygen::HTTPConnector::HTTPConnector(proxygen::HTTPConnector::Callback*, folly::HHWheelTimer*)'
/home/cortana/ClionProjects/string_from_url/src/main.cpp:116: undefined reference to `proxygen::HTTPConnector::setPlaintextProtocol(std::string const&)'
/home/cortana/ClionProjects/string_from_url/src/main.cpp:126: undefined reference to `proxygen::HTTPConnector::connectSSL(folly::EventBase*, folly::SocketAddress const&, std::shared_ptr<folly::SSLContext> const&, ssl_session_st*, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> >, std::map<folly::AsyncSocket::OptionKey, int, std::less<folly::AsyncSocket::OptionKey>, std::allocator<std::pair<folly::AsyncSocket::OptionKey const, int> > > const&, folly::SocketAddress const&, std::string const&)'
/home/cortana/ClionProjects/string_from_url/src/main.cpp:134: undefined reference to `proxygen::HTTPConnector::connect(folly::EventBase*, folly::SocketAddress const&, std::chrono::duration<long, std::ratio<1l, 1000l> >, std::map<folly::AsyncSocket::OptionKey, int, std::less<folly::AsyncSocket::OptionKey>, std::allocator<std::pair<folly::AsyncSocket::OptionKey const, int> > > const&, folly::SocketAddress const&)'
/home/cortana/ClionProjects/string_from_url/src/main.cpp:114: undefined reference to `proxygen::HTTPConnector::~HTTPConnector()'
/home/cortana/ClionProjects/string_from_url/src/main.cpp:114: undefined reference to `proxygen::HTTPConnector::~HTTPConnector()'
CMakeFiles/tutifruti.dir/src/CurlClient.cpp.o: In function `CurlService::CurlClient::connectSuccess(proxygen::HTTPUpstreamSession*)':
/home/cortana/ClionProjects/string_from_url/src/CurlClient.cpp:81: undefined reference to `proxygen::HTTPUpstreamSession::newTransaction(proxygen::HTTPTransactionHandler*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [/home/cortana/ClionProjects/string_from_url/build/tutifruti] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/tutifruti.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/tutifruti.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [tutifruti] Error 2
```

In here, the library is successfully added but can't link itself to these mentioned headers. On checking online, I found out that I need to add binaries of the required header (to include the cpp too).

My cmake uptil now is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(string_from_url)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/build)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )


set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)
add_executable(tutifruti ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/main.cpp src/CurlClient.cpp)

target_link_libraries(tutifruti gflags)
target_link_libraries(tutifruti glog)

target_link_libraries(tutifruti folly)
target_link_libraries(tutifruti proxygenhttpserver)
target_link_libraries(tutifruti SDL2)
target_link_libraries(tutifruti GL)
target_link_libraries(tutifruti GLU)
target_link_libraries(tutifruti glut)
target_link_libraries(tutifruti GLEW)
target_link_libraries(tutifruti wangle)
target_link_libraries(tutifruti pthread)
target_link_libraries(tutifruti config++)
target_link_libraries(tutifruti opencv_core)
target_link_libraries(tutifruti opencv_highgui)
target_link_libraries(tutifruti opencv_imgproc)
target_link_libraries(tutifruti opencv_videoio)
target_link_libraries(tutifruti opencv_objdetect)
target_link_libraries(tutifruti ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(tutifruti ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

Please help me out here:/

EDIT: 
Output of `find / -name "*proxygenhttpserver*" -type f` :

```
find: `/sys/kernel/debug': Permission denied
find: `/etc/cups/ssl': Permission denied
find: `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority': Permission denied
find: `/etc/ssl/private': Permission denied
find: `/proc/tty/driver': Permission denied
find: `/proc/1/task/1/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/1/task/1/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/1/task/1/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/1/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/1/map_files': Permission denied
find: `/proc/1/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/1/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/2/task/2/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/2/task/2/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/2/task/2/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/2/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/2/map_files': Permission denied
find: `/proc/2/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/2/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/3/task/3/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/3/task/3/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/3/task/3/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/3/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/3/map_files': Permission denied
find: `/proc/3/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/3/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/5/task/5/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/5/task/5/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/5/task/5/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/5/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/5/map_files': Permission denied
find: `/proc/5/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/5/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/7/task/7/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/7/task/7/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/7/task/7/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/7/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/7/map_files': Permission denied
find: `/proc/7/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/7/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/8/task/8/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/8/task/8/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/8/task/8/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/8/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/8/map_files': Permission denied
find: `/proc/8/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/8/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/9/task/9/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/9/task/9/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/9/task/9/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/9/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/9/map_files': Permission denied
find: `/proc/9/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/9/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/10/task/10/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/10/task/10/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/10/task/10/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/10/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/10/map_files': Permission denied
find: `/proc/10/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/10/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/11/task/11/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/11/task/11/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/11/task/11/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/11/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/11/map_files': Permission denied
find: `/proc/11/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/11/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/12/task/12/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/12/task/12/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/12/task/12/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/12/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/12/map_files': Permission denied
find: `/proc/12/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/12/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/13/task/13/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/13/task/13/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/13/task/13/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/13/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/13/map_files': Permission denied
find: `/proc/13/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/13/ns': Permission denied
```

and a lot more.

Comment: 1) How did you install `proxygenhttpserver`? 2) On which OS you are working?

Comment: I installed it using the instructions that were given there. I am working on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: 3) What is your output of this command: `find / -name "*proxygenhttpserver*" -type f`?

Comment: I used a docker container for a test with the `Dockerfile` provided by the project, i.e. it would be the same if I would run the command `./deps.sh && ./reinstall.sh` on a normal machine (with sudo privileges). After that, when I run this `find` command, then I find a static and a shared library of `proxygenhttpserver` in `/usr/local/lib`. Is this the same on your machine?

Comment: No, I haven't done that docker test. Do I have to run the ./deps.sh && ./reinstall.sh command on root folder or is it something else?

Comment: You should run the `find` command with `sudo`, i.e. `sudo find ...`

Comment: I assume, you're using the project `facebook/proxygen` from github.com? If yes, then in the "Installing" part, they're wrote, for installing this project, you have to start the command `./deps.sh && ./reinstall.sh`. If you want the libraries in system directories, you have to start these commands as `root` / `sudo`

Comment: Ok, will reinstall it that way then. Is the cmake correct or should I change it ? I don't know much about it and initially thought there was something missing in it because of which there was an error.

Comment: As far as I can see, your CMakeLists.txt should be correct, with the assumption, that every library, which is listed in a `target_link_libraries` line, is in a system library dir.

Comment: I installed the library using sudo and it still gives the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your link error refers to the HTTPConnector class, which is under proxygen/lib (instead of proxygen/httpserver), so you probably need to add

```
target_link_libraries(tutifruti proxygenlib)
```

to your cmake file as well.

Updated to add: I'm able to use HTTPMessage without adding the above library, so I agree with kristian that the CMakeLists.txt files is correct as is.  I do not see an answer to kristian's suggestion to run find with sudo.  That should reveal the problem.